# Open refine create ranges for numeric values

Tags: openrefine

For a current project, I got one column in Open Refine which should represent a participant's age.
I am planning on having ranges so I can work with the different ranges as nominal values.
E.g. age >18, age between 18 and 30 etc.
How do I do that in Open Refine?
Thank you very much,

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to do. If you just want to do a quick interactive analysis, you can either use numeric facets set to the appropriate ranges or create custom text facets with expressions like `value < 18` or `and(value >= 18, value <30)` which would evaluate to the text labels `true` or `false`.

If you want to add permanent labels for the ranges, you could set up the facets as above, then add a column or change an existing column to have a tag like "under18" or whatever you want to call it.